# Is the discrete logarithm equivalent to solving polynomial discrete logarithms?

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, polynomials, differential-equations, finite-fields

Suppose we can quickly solve the discrete logarithm modulo $p$. Let's say $2$ is a generator so we can quickly find $l$ for which $2^l =h$ for any given target $h$.

An interesting observation is that we can now solve any ``linear combination'' of logarithms in $l$:

Lets say we want to find $l$ for which
$$c*s^l+d*t^l = h$$
we take the logarithm with respect to $2$ of both $s$ and $t$ and let $x = 2^l$ to get a polynomial of form:
$$c'*x^a+d'*x^b =h $$
We can now solve this mod $p$, relatively quickly, and take a final discrete logarithm to recover $l$ if there is a solution.

Similarly, we can solve the ``homogeneous'' version $2^{f(l)}=h$ for any fixed polynomial $f(l)$ and $h$.

I'm wondering if there are any tricks we can use to solve the quadratic version, again, assuming discrete logarithm. That is, given fixed $h$, find $l$, if it exists, for which:

$$2^{l^2}+2^l = h$$

Comment: It's not clear to me that there is a fast algorithm known for solving the polynomial equation $c' x^a + d' x^b = h$, especially if $a$ and $b$ are large (they could be of the order of magnitude of $p$, for instance).